# Multi-Game Deck Building Tool

Tags: deck-building, online

I play Magic: The Gathering, one of my son's plays Pokemon, and the other plays Yu-Gi-Oh!

I got a deck building tool for my iPad to build Magic decks, but I am curious if there is an app for building decks for all three card games. Ideally one that knows the rules about different styles of decks and card games too.

The ideal tool would sync the decks between my iPad, Mac and Windows computers, but that may be asking to much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be interested in these projects:

[Generic Collectible Card Game](http://gccg.sourceforge.net/)

[OCTGN](http://www.octgn.net/)

[MWS](http://www.magicworkstation.com/overview.php)

For the first one, last updated end 2009 apparently and it seems there's no yugioh support (to be verified) Lots of addons though and scripting language so that might be doable.

You could also try to dig in that list here:
http://forums.mtgsalvation.com/showthread.php?t=56796

PS: I hate you for reminding me that this game is terribly addicting :)
I'll keep the link above in my favorites but will refrain from installing anything! ;)

Answer (score 2):

### [OCTGN](http://www.octgn.net/)

I'll expand on this one because it's the only tool I'm familiar with. Just to be specific, the software on that site is also known as OCTGN 2. It is the redesign of a previous application with the same name.

Anyway. OCTGN is much more than just a deck builder, you can play any game that has a module build for OCTGN. As such the focus of development rests heavily on the "playing games" aspect of the software and the deck builder is somewhat simplistic.

Still I recommend you try it, maybe it'll be enough for your needs. It will probably take quite some downloading until you have all the sets you need. They can be quite big when they include high quality pictures. I know for a fact that MtG is available for it and I think the other two games are too...